# Xcode 11: Revoked certificate, now can't submit app

Tags: xcode, certificate

I revoked a certificate because I couldn't get access to the original private key, and now in Xcode 11 I can't submit an app. I've tried to generate a new certificate but with no success so far. This is both manual and using an Xcode Managed Profile. Any advice on what to do here?
It seems that the old revoked certificate is somehow cached within Xcode.

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90721: "Certificate Revoked. The signing certificate "C=GB, O=NAME, OU=QY8KYJQS8T, CN=Apple Distribution: NAME (QY8KYJQS8T), UID=QY8KYJQS8T" with serial number 7115865899670450192 used to sign APP_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/AOO_NAME has been revoked. Learn more (https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09)."
```